SQL adding rows to each row
I have a table like this
id   sequence  phase  characteristics
1      1        300      001
2      1        300      001
2      2        300      002
..

and another table that contain a lot of characteristics for each phase
phase  characteristics
300      003
300      004
300      005
....

I need to add all the characteristics to each id/sequence where phase is 300
For better understanding what I need is
id   sequence  phase  characteristics
1      1        300      001
1      1        300      003
1      1        300      004
1      1        300      005
2      1        300      001
2      1        300      003
2      1        300      004
2      1        300      005
2      2        300      002
2      2        300      003
2      2        300      004
2      2        300      005
..

I have attempted several solutions, could someone please offer assistance? Thank you in advance

If I understood you correctly, you want all records from the first table and additionally all matching records from the second table. That would mean to UNION the first table with the JOINed result of table 1 and 2.
SELECT t1.id, t1.sequence, t1.phase, t1.characteristics
FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.id, t1.sequence, t1.phase, t2.characteristics
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.phase = t2.phase

Remove the ALL from the UNION ALL if you don't want duplicates.

Like the simplicity

You can use a CROSS JOIN between the to a unique UNION between table1 and chatacterists and table, to get all chatacterists to a phase.
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 
         
1 as id,      1   as sequence ,    300 as phase ,      '001' characteristics
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
2   ,   1 ,       300 ,     '001'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
2     , 2 ,       300 ,     001),
  characteristics as
  (SELECT
    
300 phase,      '003' characteristics
UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  300 ,     '004'
  UNION ALL 
SELECT
  300  ,    '005'),
  GET_PasE_combinations as
  (SELECT  phase,     characteristics  FROM table1
  UNION 
  SELECT  phase,     characteristics  FROM characteristics)
  
    SELECT
    s.id,   s.sequence,  s.phase , c.characteristics
    FROM  table1 s  CROSS JOIN GET_PasE_combinations c
WHERE  s.phase = c.phase
ORDER BY s.id,   s.sequence




id
sequence
phase
characteristics




1
1
300
1


1
1
300
3


1
1
300
4


1
1
300
5


2
1
300
5


2
1
300
4


2
1
300
3


2
1
300
1


2
2
300
1


2
2
300
3


2
2
300
4


2
2
300
5



fiddle

So it looks like you want to expand the rows in the tables for each id/sequence combination where the phase is 300.
Here a SQL query
WITH Allcharachteristics AS (
    SELECT '001' AS characteristic 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '003'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '004'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '005'
    -- Add more characteristics if needed 
)    
SELECT t.id, t.sequence, t.phase, c.characteristic
FROM YourTable t
CROSS JOIN Allcharachteristics c
WHERE t. phase = 300
ORDER BY t.id, t.sequence,  c.characteristic;

